# jQuery .animate - callback function not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to set up three divs to animate (as an example) and once animation is complete on all animations, run the function that kicks off the animation again.

The callback works fine if I stick an alert in there rather than the function name, but with the function name, nothing:

```
$(function () {
function runIt() 
{
    $('.three').animate({'background-position-x': "-200px", 'background-position-y': "0px"}, 500,'linear');
    $('.two').animate({'background-position-x': "-400px", 'background-position-y': "0px"}, 500, 'linear');
    $('.one').animate({'background-position-x': "-600px", 'background-position-y': "0px"}, 500, 'linear', runIt);
}
runIt();
});
```

The animation speed would be significantly bumped up, it's just easier for the sake of testing to have it only take half a second!

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/erinfreeman/J9Htj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9Htj/35/). Works in Safari 6.

```
$(function () {
    function runIt() 
    {
        $('.three').css({'background-position-x': "0", 'background-position-y': "0px"})
            .animate({'background-position-x': "-200px", 'background-position-y': "0px"}, 500);
        $('.two').css({'background-position-x': "0", 'background-position-y': "0px"})
            .animate({'background-position-x': "-400px", 'background-position-y': "0px"}, 500);
        $('.one').css({'background-position-x': "0", 'background-position-y': "0px"})
            .animate({'background-position-x': "-600px", 'background-position-y': "0px"}, 500, runIt);
    }
    runIt();
});
```

Reset the values on every iteration.
​

Comment: Aha!.. and there is that moment of clarity, I guess it was repeating the function but the background position wasn't really changing on those iterations. I obviously didn't think that one through! Thank you! :)